# m-aside-left sidebar into a div

Tags: html, css, metronic

In my web application, I have a fixed sidebar in all the pages for the menu. In a particular page, in addition to the fixed sidebar, I created a div in the body of this page and I want to insert another sidebar aligned to the left of this div.
In order to create my general sidebar, I used the class `m-aside-left` of metronic, but now if I use that class into my new div to create also the new sidebar it overwrites the previous one. What am I doing wrong? Which class do I have to use in the div in order to create this new sidebar?

**html of my div**

```
<div class="m-portlet__body">
  <div class="m-section">
    <!-- BEGIN: Left Aside -->
    <div id="m_aside_left" class="m-grid__item left m-aside-left m-aside-left--skin-dark">
      <!-- BEGIN: Aside Menu -->
      <div id="m_ver_menu" class="m-aside-menu  m-aside-menu--skin-dark"
        m-menu-vertical="1" m-menu-scrollable="1" m-menu-dropdown-timeout="500" style="position: relative">
        <ul class="m-menu__nav  m-menu__nav--dropdown-submenu-arrow" id="aside-menu" style="padding-top: 0px">
          <div *ngFor="let item of parameterStruct">
            <!-- single item -->
            <li *ngIf="!item.isSubClass" class="m-menu__item  sa-m-menu-item">
              <a class="m-menu__link sa-m-menu__link sa-m-menu__link">
              <span class="m-menu__link-wrap">
              <span class="m-menu__link-text icon-padding sideBar-text"
                style="padding-left: 15px; ">{{ item.description |translate }}
              </span>
              </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <!-- end single item -->            
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- END: Aside Menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- END: Left Aside -->  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u plz send the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that, the new sidebar is overlapping with the previous sidebar.

You need to put the html of New sidebar after the div having id "m_ver_menu" is closed or having after its closing tag.

Please add the your HTML code after comment ""

```
<div class="m-portlet__body">
```

{{ item.description |translate }}

```
  <!-- Start: Aside Menu 2  -->



  <!-- End: Aside Menu 2 -->

</div>
<!-- END: Left Aside -->
```

Comment: please provide me the code of your solution, because I do not understand what are you saying

Comment: I am aupdating comment for the same.

Comment: The content of item.description has to be in the sidebar

Comment: it is auto correcting on the editor, can you share me full code or any js fiddle link.